# Have any Hindu scholars/commentators touched on the topic of relationship between Brahma and saraswati?

Tags: puranas, brahma, adi-shankaracharya, saraswati, brahmanas

Have any scholars commented on the whole lust of prajapati in shatpatha brahmana and other texts describing them as couple, what does shankaracharya and other scholars say?